# Ionic - How to load images for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ionic-framework

This is my first attempt at making a mobile app and I'm very new to this. So far I've understood that you have to create several images of the same image for different densities and displays.

For Android you have to place them in ***folders named drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, ect***. And for iOS you have to create 2 images - 1 for retina and other for non-retina and add ***@2x*** for the retina file name.

I'm a bit confused about how the implementation is done for this.

My image folder structure goes like this,

```
Resources  
- Android
-- drawable-ldpi
  --- logo.png
-- drawable-mdpi
  --- logo.png
-- drawable-hdpi
  --- logo.png

- iOS
-- logo.png
-- logo@2x.png
```

So how does the url for a img tag looks like?

If I put

```
<img src = "resources/android/drawable/logo.png">
```

How do I say where to look for the iOS image?

I'm very new to mobile development and Ionic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Ionic Framework you don't put anything in the Android/iOS folders. Put all your images to www/img. Then you reference them only in Ionic html files like:

`<img src="img/logo.png">`

If you run `ionic build` the framework will take care of sending the files to the appropriate Android/iOS folders.

> How do I say where to look for the iOS image?

Depends. Normally Ionic put image files for iOS in two folders.

**1. project_folder/project_name/Resources**

**2. project_folder/www/img**

But I said said above, you don't need to worry where does iOS and Android image files are. The framework takes care of that.

Comment: Does that mean I have to put only one image inside the img folder? If so do I put a high resolution image?

Comment: Yes, you put only one image inside img folder. It depends on you what resolution you will choose.